# excel find tab matching column header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is my code and I will try to explain what I want to achieve.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A4,'[Scarification.xlsx]Aut 16'!$A:$A,1,FALSE),E$3,""),"")
```

So `Aut 16` is the sheet I am looking for and it works fine,
it is pulling this data into a column that is also called `Aut 16`.

At some point that column will become `Aut 17` so I would like the `Aut 16` in the code to change to that value (`Aut 17`), the value always refers to another tab.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please add some sample data with desired results to help us understanding your issue. (take a screenshot, upload it to e.g. [imgur](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), then post the link in your question; or you can format your data as a table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).

Answer (score 0):

Change the string

```
'[Scarification.xlsx]Aut 16'!$A:$A
```

to

```
INDIRECT('[Scarification.xlsx]Aut '&num&'!$A:$A)
```

the & character is a concatenation character and the `num` variable can be an adress where the number is (if the number is on cell C4, for example) or you could create a [name](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) called `num` with a formula to return the number 17.

Comment: That is correct. I forgot the INDIRECT function. The correct formula would be INDIRECT('[Scarification.xlsx]Aut '&num&'!$A:$A).